# How do I put text as a background instead of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background

I need to know how i can set text to the background of the scratchcard game i am building. I will put an example of the code i have tried.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#krasvak').wScratchPad({
      scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
        console.log(percent);
        if (percent > 70)
        {
            this.clear();
            window.alert("U heeft uw code gekrast");
            window.location.href='compleet.php';
        }
      }
    });
    $('#krasvak').wScratchPad('bg', 'images/slide1.png');
    $('#krasvak').wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');
    $('#krasvak').wScratchPad('size', 15);
    $('#krasvak').wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default');

  </script>
```

If anybody could help me out i would really appriciate it.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: @putvande: I believe you can, but it's a hack (haven't tried though). All current browsers now [support SVG backgrounds](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css), and also [data URIs](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri). Do you see where I'm going? :) However, it's much easier to just have some div (or svg) behind, if possible.

Comment: A text has only the information of characters. To show a text on screen, it needs information of font, size, style etc. and position, placement, colors etc. I believe you can do too.

Comment: Use z-index and place a div at bottom with the text?

Comment: I will try the z-index.